# Можно ли параметры в прототипе писать так? Если да, то почему нельзя написать параметры с переменными?

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки, int

Пример из книги Р. Лафоре.
Зачем автор написал в прототипе функции параметры без переменной. Какой от этого толк? Есть ли какие-то преимущества такой записи? В чём смысл? Почему нельзя было просто как обычно написать в прототипе 
(int &num1, int &num2)???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    void order(int &, int &); //прототип
    int n1 = 99, n2 = 11;
    int n3 = 22, n4 = 88;
    order(n1, n2);
    order(n3, n4);
    cout << "n1 = " << n1 << endl;
    cout << "n2 = " << n2 << endl;
    cout << "n3 = " << n3 << endl;
    cout << "n4 = " << n4 << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
void order(int &num1, int &num2) {
    if (num1 > num2) {
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного изменил вопрос

Comment: А в книге объявление функции `order` размещено в теле `main`?

Comment: Что за странный вопрос??? Наоборот, логичнее спросить зачем *указывать* имена параметров а прототипе. "...почему нельзя написать параметры с переменными?" Почему вы решили, что этого делать "нельзя"?

Comment: Также, в С++ нет никаких "прототипов" вообще. В С++ есть только *объявления функций*. Прототипы бывают только в С. Слово "прототип" в С++ терминологии встречается только в рамках составного термина "function prototype scope".

Comment: Действительно, странный вопрос. Если две записи имеют одинаковый эффект, то обычно спрашивают, зачем использовать более длинную запись. Более короткую понятно зачем - чтобы меньше писать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете писать, как с именами параметров, так и без них. В стандарте C++ не указано обязательное наличие имен для параметров в прототипах функций. Преимущества: краткость. Недостатки: сложно понять, зачем нужен тот или иной параметр.

Answer (score 4):

А **зачем** они в прототипе? Они все равно не используются; все, что нужно знать компилятору - это типы параметров.

Ну, а вот при определении функции, когда вы описываете, что с этими параметрами делаете - без имени не обойтись...

P.S. В *объявлении* имена могут носить *описательный* характер - тогда они на своем месте - например, что-то вроде `search(int * table_to_search, int element, bool(*equal_func)(int,int))` - ну, чтоб было понятно, что за аргументы передавать в функцию. `num1` и `num2` никакой дополнительной ясности не вносят...

Comment: "А зачем они в прототипе?" - чтобы при взгляде на прототип было видно что это за параметры.

Comment: @Croessmah Это две ссылки на `int`. Названия аргументов типа `num1` - ничего не говорят пользователю Я еще понимаю объявление типа `func(double product_price, int count_of_product, double discount)` - когда имена параметров что-то описывают...

Comment: Так (с описывающими именами), обычно и делают (часто вместо комментария ...)

Comment: @Harry спасибо!